# É possível importar uma função do Sublime para o VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublime-text

Existe uma função que uso bastante no sublime que é o <kbd>F12</kbd>:

```
{ "keys": ["f12"], "command": "goto_definition" },
```

Ele apresenta todas as funções com o mesmo nome e até guia para o arquivo de destino dessa função/estilo. Eu queria incorporar essa mesma função no VsCode. Tentei alguns exemplos mas nenhum ainda deu resultado.

Comment: Talvez te ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995468/vscode-c-sharp-go-to-definition-f12-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No VS Code exite o `Go to Definition` e o `Peek Definition` Como vc pode consultar na documentação oficial:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_peek

Ao que me parece vc precisa mais do `Peek`, veja como ele funciona nessas imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queria usar alguma extenção, acredito que essa deve te ser útil: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CtrlClickGoToDefinition

---

**No CSS**

Agora caso queira pegar informações do `style` no CSS basta vc aperta `Ctrl` e faz o `hover` sobre o estilo, e se vc clicar com `Ctrl` vc vai direto pro arquivo `.css` onde está a classe, ou vc pode usar o `Peek Definition` para ver "localmente" os estilos dessa classe que estão lá no `.css`

Veja na imagen:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira também existe extensão para fazer isso: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek